# kdenlive won't see my external hard drive

Tags: video, drive, kdenlive

kdenlive won't see my external hard drive. I have heard that it's a common issue. ..is there a new fix yet ?

[image]

Comment: You have provided no OS/release details, nor details such as if the drive was mounted.

Comment: Could be a snap?

Comment: I had a similar issue with the Kdenlive snap and switch to using the appimage instead.

Answer (score -1):

I have found out that there are two versions of Kdenlive. One version works great at the Ubuntu Store.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Sadly, without specifying which one works great, this answer isn't of much use to anyone. Please review https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: the version that works has the colorful logo of the director film strip...... is it " a fork of Kdenlive or something ?

Comment: I don't know what you've done but you can certainly find out. It it's a snap package you can get this information with the command `snap list | grep kdenlive` if it's a deb package you can get it with the command `sudo dpkg list | grep kdenlive`

Comment: Oh! I am speaking of the KDE version of Kdenlive in the Ubuntu store.. ....The KDE Kdenlive version on Ubuntu 20.04 Does work. ...but the SNAP Kdenlive version does Not work......to open my external hard drive. Weird  LOL....it's all good.

Comment: Every package has a version number which has value in determining what the problem might be. You can obtain then by the methods I described. Since you aren't using the snap variant it's a deb package.